# Conditional Access on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online

We have E5 account for Office 365. We have issue on SharePoint Online. My issue is that We have created one site collection and in that site collection one page is going to be access by external users. We did all the setting and now we can send email to external users and programmatically we add external user to certain SharePoint Group and this group have access to particular page.

External user is getting email too. Once external user clicked on it, it will take to our tenant and if the external user email is not Microsoft account than he can log-in successfully but it cannot access the resources. I get below error message

> Your sign-in was successful but does not meet the criteria to access
>   this resource. For example, you might be signing in from a browser,
>   app, or location that is restricted by your admin

How can I solve it.

Comment: Are your users in a restricted country?  https://products.office.com/en-us/business/international-availability

Comment: Our user base are from Kuwait

Answer (score 0):

You will need to edit the conditions on your policy to meet your requirement.  You did not list what you currently have so it's hard to say what needs to be done to fix it.  You can find your policies under Azure AD in the portal.  This post outlines where those settings can be found.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/skypehybridguy/2017/08/31/microsoft-teams-restrict-usage-with-azure-ad-conditional-access/

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But In my case though I am Global Admin inside Conditional Access everything is disable.

Comment: I could resolve the issue. Actually we need to have P1 or P2 Subscription to manage Conditional Access. Once we activated and we could configure the conditional access